# Not showing images in a html5 canvas (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, closures

I'm trying to show chess pieces on a board. The thing is: IF I let the "alert(img.src)" (thus creating a lot of alert boxes...), pieces are gonna show at the right places, BUT if I remove the alert, it shows only one piece in the up-right corner of my canvas.

What do you think is happening? Thanks!

```
for (var i=1;i<9;i++){
    for (var j=1;j<9;j++){
        var img=new Image();
        img.onload=function(){
                ctx.drawImage(img,p+sqs*(i-1)+(sqs-32)/2,p+bds-sqs*j+(sqs-32)/2,32,32);
        };
        img.src="img/"+squares[i][j]+".png";
        //alert(img.src);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please reproduce it on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried but the problem is my script file uses images. Excellent website though.

Comment: Replace the image URL with a random image URL like this one http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f0/Chess_kdt45.svg/50px-Chess_kdt45.svg.png

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time. I couldn't manage to see a "Result", so I uploaded my files: http://www.mediafire.com/?c8qwut8ls8dgl1v     .Thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is Javascript closures.  If you don't know about this, [look it up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops%3a_A_common_mistake).  If you add an `alert(i+','+j+','+img.src)` to your onload function and run your program you'll see that the onload function is using the final values of the loop variable - i.e. 9,9.

To pass the values you actually want to pass, you need to create a new scope, using a self-invoking anonymous function.  So your code should look like this:

```
for (var i=1;i<9;i++){
    for (var j=1;j<9;j++){
        var img=new Image();
        (function(i,j,img){
            img.onload=function(){
                ctx.drawImage(img,sqs*(i-1),sqs*(j-1),32,32);
            };
            img.src="http://placekitten.com/"+(30+i)+"/"+(30+j);
        })(i,j,img) ;
    }
}
```

Click here for a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/U2WYz/).

By the way, the reason your code worked when you had the `alert(img.src)` statement was that you were stopping the loop at every iteration, which had the effect that your onload function (which doesn't execute until the image is loaded) was using the correct `i` and `j`.  Without the `alert` statement, the loop set `(i,j)` to `(9,9)` by the time any of the images had loaded.

Comment: Thank you so much, not only for finding the error but also for taking the time to explain in detail. I am new at javascript and this helped me a lot. Thanks again.